# Stuck with python multiple twinx axis graph using matlibplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hello I'm trying to make a graph with one Y axis and 4 X axis

I don't want to make separate graphs and was wondering if it is possible to put multiple X axis using the twinx() command.

The problem I'm having is that the final axis I'm trying to add ends up appearing on both sides of the graph and I just want it on the left.

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot 
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist as AA 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

host = host_subplot(111, axes_class=AA.Axes)

par1 = host.twinx()
par2 = host.twinx()

new_fixed_axis = par2.get_grid_helper().new_fixed_axis
par2.axis["right"] = new_fixed_axis(loc="right",axes=par2,offset=(60, 0))
par2.axis["right"].toggle(all=True)

host.set_xlabel("Y axis")
host.set_ylabel("X axis 1 on the left")
par1.set_ylabel("X axis 2 on the right") par2.set_ylabel("X axis 3 on the right")

par3 = host.twinx()

new_fixed_axis = par3.get_grid_helper().new_fixed_axis
par3.axis["left"] = new_fixed_axis(loc="left",axes=par3,offset=(-60, 0))
par3.axis["left"].toggle(all=True)

par3.set_ylabel("X axis 4 on the left")

p1, = host.plot([1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4], label="1")
p2, = par1.plot([1,2,3,4],[2,2,2,2], label="2")
p3, = par2.plot([1,2,3,4],[3,3,2,1], label="3")
p4, = par3.plot([1,2,3,4],[1,1,2.5,3.5], label="4")

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the visibility to False.

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot 
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist as AA 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

host = host_subplot(111, axes_class=AA.Axes)
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.1, left=0.2, right=0.8, top=0.9)

par1 = host.twinx()
par2 = host.twinx()
par3 = host.twinx()
par3.axis["right"].set_visible(False)

new_fixed_axis = par2.get_grid_helper().new_fixed_axis
par2.axis["right"] = new_fixed_axis(loc="right",axes=par2,offset=(60, 0))

host.set_xlabel("Y axis")
host.set_ylabel("X axis 1 on the left")
par1.set_ylabel("X axis 2 on the right")
par2.set_ylabel("X axis 3 on the right")
par3.set_ylabel("X axis 4 on the left")


new_fixed_axis = par3.get_grid_helper().new_fixed_axis
par3.axis["left"] = new_fixed_axis(loc="left",axes=par3,offset=(-60, 0))


p1, = host.plot([1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4], label="1")
p2, = par1.plot([1,2,3,4],[2,2,2,2], label="2")
p3, = par2.plot([1,2,3,4],[3,3,2,1], label="3")
p4, = par3.plot([1,2,3,4],[1,1,2.5,3.5], label="4")

plt.show()
```

By the way, when asking such a question, it would be helpful not to reverse the standard understanding of x-axis and y-axis!  Also, I had to add a `subplot_adjust` to see the whole figure with mpl's standard settings.

Comment: Thanks, that was a nice easy solution. I didn't know about the visibility setting.

Comment: Hearty agreement on not "flipping" the standard X and Y.  Seeing `set_xlabel("Y axis")` made the hairs on the back of my neck stand up...